# Find view by its ID in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm still new to iOS, Swift and SwiftUI...

I created a content view using a SwiftUI and then I added the view to my view controller in Swift

```
let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: ChildUIView())
addChild(childView)
childView.view.frame = viewController.bounds
viewController.addSubview(childView.view)
```

The code above works fine, but then how can I target a view that's in my rootView SwiftUI

In Android Java, I can do something like this

```
ScrollView scrollView = childView.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
```

Here in my Swift file, I try to do this

```
let scrollView = childView.rootView.id(scrollView)
```

But I don't know if that's the right syntax to use

And then I'm trying to pass the data type as a ScrollView.

```
let scrollView: ScrollView = childView.rootView.id(scrollView) as! ScrollView
```

But I'm getting an error saying, `Generic parameter Content could not be inferred in cast to ScrollView`.

Probably, I get this error because I don't know how it's done.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This isn't something one would normally do in a reactive UI framework (try to get a reference to a child view). Can you explain why you need the reference? There might be a better way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have so many things to do with it... And not just the ScrollView, but with other Views too

Comment: "I have so many things to do with it" -- Like I said, you may want to explain what you're trying to do and someone could give some guidance, because this is really antithetical to the way the SwiftUI framework works.

Comment: Firstly, is there a reason why you are combining UIKit and SwiftUI?  Normally you would only do so if you are introducing SwiftUI to an existing, UIKit based app. You would just add an instance of `ChildView` to your `ScrollView`.  SwiftUI uses a declarative style, so you would say `ScrollView { ChildUIView() }`.  Secondly, SwiftUI views are immutable structs and so tend to be ephemeral.  You bind data to them and when the data changes, SwiftUI recreates the view

Comment: As @jnpdx said, you don't "do things to" a SwiftUI view.  You change the data model that is bound to the view and the view updates itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... I finally found a solution. Using the `viewWithTag` method.

First I have to give my `ScrollView` a tag of `int` type, maybe `100` and then refer to it like this

```
childView.view.viewWithTag(100)
```